# Many problems with windows cloned by clonezilla

Tags: windows-7, command-line, disk-image, clonezilla

After many attempts I've installed a clonezilla image of my old computer on my new notebook but I did this wrong. Windows starts but I need to launch explorer manually, I have the `This copy of Windows is not genuine`, when I want to click on computer/control panel/screen resolution... I have `explorer.exe No such interface supported`. My volume label is not C like my old computer but G I think it could be the cause of many problems.
I can run cmd.exe  without `run as administrator`, when I click on "run as administrator" I have `G:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe The specified path does not exist`
To solve all this problems I need to have a cmd with administrator privileges but impossible to click on run as admin, I ve tryied to launch cmd as admin via a command line but it ask my administrator password and I don't know it. Any solutions? 
Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Windows does not react well to imaging across different hardware.

This is due to the drivers and underlying system, as well as the underlying motherboard and HDD serial number that are used to control Windows activation.

Your best option is to install Windows fresh, and migrate your **data** (i.e. documents, music etc.).

Comment: Agreed. Acronis with Universal Restore can mitigate some, if not most, of the issues, but migrating is cheaper ;)

Comment: Ok I will install a fresh windows and migrate my datas after. Thanks you!